# Using Curly Braces with $_REQUEST to retrieve its indexes

Tags: php

I've been reviewing a sample code to learn PHP and what I saw made me confused in the following code:

```
$in = $_REQUEST;
require_once 'utils.php';
require_once 'utils_user.php';
require_once 'utils_email.php';
require_once 'utils_affiliate.php';

#Load Settings
$globalSettings = parse_ini_file("settings.ini", true);

if(isInDevelMode())
{
    $system = "devel";
}

if(strlen($in{'system'} > 0))
{
    $system = strip_tags($in{'system'});
}
```

Here a variable called `$in` was created and `$_REQUEST` was assigned to it and then later on in the second if-statement it was written like `if(strlen($in{'system'} > 0))` and I don't quite understand what `$in{'system'}` here. It doesn't look like an array but $_REQUEST is an array-like to retrieve its content. Can somebody tell me what these curly braces are used for after `$in` variable...

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The curly braces can be used to access array keys instead of the square ones.

```
$array{'a'} === $array['a']
```

The syntax is exactly the same with the only difference that curly brackets can't be used for pushing values:

```
$array{} = 'x'; // doesn't work
$array[] = 'x'; // works
```

This alternative syntax was originally intended for use when accessing string offsets. But now it is just an old, obsolete syntax, which is likely to be deprecated. (Actually it already was deprecated some time while PHP 5.3 was developed.)

Answer (score 1):

Never saw that notation. But other than array it can't be nothing.

Also I think there is an error here:

```
strlen($in{'system'} > 0)
```

should be

```
strlen($in{'system'}) > 0
```

Dunno who wrote that code but it's pretty a bad code, maybe someone coming from other languages

Comment: I believe he is coming from PERL.

Answer (score 1):

This is an [alternative variable syntax](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php) and variable interpolation. All of the following are the same thing.

```
$in{'system'}
$in['system']
$_REQUEST{'system'}
$_REQUEST['system']
```

The `${''}` syntax is not common in PHP and more or less legacy syntax from Perl. Also, don't use `$_REQUEST`. It's a security risk.

#### UPDATE

My answer assumes that the user *intended* to use variable interpolation for `system` but was confused by the alternate syntax.

I believe what your intended code is `$in[$system]` versus `$in{'system'}`.

Comment: But why choose one over the other? Any gain?

Comment: `{'system'}` is NOT variable interpolation, but the alternative array syntax.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation later you added.

Comment: See update, but basically it's just support for *more than one way to do it*. From my experience, the bottom 3 are the most common.

Comment: @nikic, it is when `system` is being evaluated to `'devel'`. But to be fair, not all my examples are variable interpolation. I have updated my answer to appease the downvoters.

Comment: @Jason: `{'system'}` does not evaluate to `['devel']`.

Comment: @nikic, then that's the problem.

Comment: @Jason: I think you slightly misunderstood what `$in{'system'}` means: It is exactly the same as `$in['system']`. And that's exactly what the code wants to have.

Comment: @nikic, I'm with you. But I did assume that the OP was getting the incorrect value when they merely wanted an explanation. I corrected this in my comparisons. Thanks.

Comment: Actually, what the coder wanted to is `$in[$system]` something like this and `{'system'}` becomes either `devel` or `live` since he is trying to reach `devel` section or `live` section defined in `setting.ini` file and also `$systemSettings = $globalSettings[$system];` he said something like this to reach the proper variables defined in `setting.ini`

Comment: But I tried it on my code window and what it said "Undefined index:" and didn't work out.

Comment: @Braveyard, it sounds like your question is indeed two part. I would update your question to be more clear about this and reopen the question. Note my update.

Comment: Most probably the answer is yes. Thanks.